# jenkins maven job stuck at "scanning for projects"

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am facing an issue where maven style jenkins job often gets stuck for hours at the "Scanning for Projects" phase. 
As per http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/any-ideas-why-Scanning-for-projects-is-very-slow-td5870457.html, I tried using a frestyle job and it works just fine without ever getting stuck at scanning phase.

However, converting to a freestyle job is not an option as we currently leverage some of the features of maven job such as "Perform Maven Release" option.

Is this one of the known issues and does anyone else is facing the same? I couldn't find many people complaining for it apart from the one I shared one.

Does anyone know of a possible solution?

Versions: Jenkins 2.46.3 and maven 3.0.5

```
12:11:13 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
……
…..
12:11:18 [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN         
================================================
12:11:18 [DEBUG] Project: com.X.X.X.X:2.2.2-p1d1-SNAPSHOT
12:11:18 [DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, deploy]
12:11:18 [DEBUG] Style:   Regular
12:11:18 [DEBUG] 
=======================================================================
14:20:58 [INFO]                                                                         
14:21:03 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:21:03 [INFO] Building XX 2.2.2-p1d1-SNAPSHOT
14:21:03 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:21:03 [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
14:21:03 [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
```

Comment: Did you try with a more recent version of Jenkins, updated version of the Maven plugin, and a maven 3.5.3?

Comment: I can try that but not sure if that will fix the issue as I don't see any fix related to the same.